# .each() to search for a background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am looking for the highlighted element. I cannot seem to get inside the `.each()` function. Do I need to navigate down to the .`resultsselected` div since it's inside of a div itself? I am at a loss.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        console.log('ready ');
        $('.resultsselected [background-color]').each(function() {
            var match = 'Green'; // match background-color:

            console.log(' looking ');
            if ($(this).css('background-color') == match) {
                $(this)[0].scrollIntoView();
                console.log(' found it ');
            }
            else console.log(' nope ');
        });
    });
```

All of this is in a `ListView` Here is my `SelectedItemTemplate`

```
                            <SelectedItemTemplate>
                                <div class="results resultsselected">
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LineLinkButton" runat="server">
                                        <asp:Label ID="" runat="server" Text='<%# %>' />
                                        <asp:Label ID="" runat="server" Text='<%# %>' />
                                        <asp:Label ID="" runat="server" Text='<%# %>' />
                                        <asp:Label ID="" runat="server" Text='<%# %>' />
                                </asp:LinkButton>
                              </div>
                         </SelectedItemTemplate>
```

My `ItemTemplate` is similar but without the `resultsselected` class just the `results` class.

EDIT: I took out the `.each()` and now I get in the console *ready*  *looking*  *nope*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        console.log('ready ');
            var match = 'rgb(0, 128, 0)'; // match background-color:

            console.log(' looking ');
            if ($('.resultsselected [background-color]').css('background-color') == match) {
                $('.resultsselected [background-color]')[0].scrollIntoView();
                console.log(' found it ');
            }
            else console.log(' nope ');
    });
```

I type this into my console

```
$('.resultsselected').css('background-color')
```

and get this

```
"rgb(0, 128, 0)"
```

I am really not understanding now.

Comment: What are you using to highlight the element (server or client-side)? The looping you are asking about would be very inefficient. Better to add a `.highlight` class that you can target with jQuery

Comment: Have you tried just using `$('.resultsselected').each(function(){...`?

Comment: Try this selector: `$('.resultsselected')` instead.

Comment: You should do this inside the `each()` loop: `console.log($(this).css('background-color'));`

Comment: `$('.resultsselected [background-color]')` is quite an interesting approach. What does it do?

Comment: @ElliotM Yes, I have.

Comment: Could you post your html?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I can't even get in the loop. none on my logs fire after `ready`. I am wanting to search through my list for the highlighted element and scroll it into view so the user sees which is selected. I am dealing with a small div (`300px` in height) with around 5-20 lines. Only 3 show at a time.

Comment: @user2690363 have you tried Andy's suggestion? I essentially said what he said in my previous comment.

Comment: Yeah, post the HTML or set up a jsfiddle if you can't get it to work.

Comment: @Andy I posted more info.

Comment: And is that template being generated, you can see it in the sourcecode? Because `$('.resultsselected')` will pick that class up no problem.

Comment: @Andy Yes. All the items that are not selected have `.results` as a class and the selected `.resultsselected`

Comment: When you load the JS does it say 'looking' now, given the answers you've received?

Comment: @Andy No, like I said in my post, I am not even getting into the .each(). There will only ever be one item with the class `.resultsselected` though. So could I just drop the .each()?

Comment: Then I suspect you have errors further up your code that are preventing that from running. Check the console log.

Comment: @Andy checkout the edit to my post

Comment: My point still stands. If you're not getting the 'looking' notification then something else is wrong. You should also check your CSS to check the how the background-color is being applied to that element.

Comment: I made it to `looking`. After I took off the each I didn't remove the ` [background-color]` from it. Now it's there. I just need to find a way to get it to scroll into view. Apparently `.scrollToView() isn't working. And by that I mean I've tried all I can to get it to work and cannot. Looking for something else to get it move into view.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the two selectors, the one in `each` and the one doing the matching. I don't know what `scrollIntoView` does but it looks a bit iffy.

```
$('.resultsselected').each(function() {
  var match = 'Green'; // match background-color:
  console.log(' looking ');
  if ($(this).css('backgroundColor') == match) {
    $(this)[0].scrollIntoView();
    console.log(' found it ');
  } else {
    console.log(' nope ');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      if($('.resultsselected').css('background-color') == 'green'){
           $(this)[0].scrollIntoView();
      }
});
```

I've did not tested this but it should work.